# What is the proper way to open a url from a scope in c++?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, scopes

What is the proper way to open a url from a scope in c++?

This is what I've tried (This function is called from the ActivationResponse.):

```
static void open_url(std::string const& uri) {
//    url_dispatch_send(uri.c_str(), NULL, NULL);
/*    
 *    I found this in the libertine-scope, but I wasn't able to import
 *    the right libraries
 */

//    Qt.openUrlExternally(uri.c_str());
/*    
 *    I found this at https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/platform/guides/url-dispatcher-guide/ 
 *    and https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/apps/qml/tutorials/register-your-app-url-dispatcher/
 *    but it is actually meant to be used in QML, so it isn't recognized.
 *    I hoped it would work by using QtQuick or QtQml
 */

//    QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(QString(uri), QUrl::TolerantMode));
//    QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("http://www.google.com", QUrl::TolerantMode));
/*    
 *    I found this at https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/platform/guides/url-dispatcher-guide/ 
 *    and http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl
 *    this compiles, but the scope crashes on execution.
 *    
 */
}
```

edit:
To be more specific, the three functions I commented are the three different options I've found and tried. Non of them would work. In the comment under the functions, I've tried to explain what didn't work.

The function open_url is called from the ActivationResponse like this:

```
Action::Action(unity::scopes::Result const&         result,
               unity::scopes::ActionMetadata const& metadata,
               Action::OpenUriAction                open_uri)
        : sc::ActivationQueryBase(result, metadata)
        , open_uri_(open_uri)
{
}

sc::ActivationResponse
Action::activate()
{
    open_uri_(result().uri());
    return sc::ActivationResponse(sc::ActivationResponse::Status::NotHandled);
}
```

Comment: This should probably be asked on [so]. If you do ask there, make sure to clarify what this code is supposed to do and what it is actually doing. Also, I don't know much C++, but aren't you just showing comments?

Comment: Do they know anything about Ubuntu Touch at stack Overflow?

Comment: Some will, yes. I may have been too hasty here though. Asking about developing software that is somehow specific to Ubuntu is indeed on topic here. If you [edit] to clarify what you're doing and show only code as `code`, making the comments into text we can read and understand that explains the situation in more detail, I can reopen this one.

Comment: Why is this closed? I have the answer, and I wanted to post it here...

Comment: Well, this is a bit of a borderline case. As I said in my previous comment, I may have been wrong in closing it. Now that I see your second block of code, I understand you're using unity-specific libraries (is that correct?), which would indeed make this on topic and I shouldn't have closed it. Sorry! In any case, I've now reopened it, please do post your answer.

Comment: It's a bit odd, I have to know the answer on the question, to be able to know how to formulate the question right. But, when you look at the tutorial, there are far less words spend to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, there is a good way to do this.

1: in the scope-class you have to override the activate-method

```
unity::scopes::ActivationQueryBase::UPtr NewsScope::activate(const sc::Result &result,
                                              const unity::scopes::ActionMetadata &metadata) {
    return unity::scopes::ActivationQueryBase::UPtr(new NewsAction(result, metadata));
}
```

2: In the unity::scopes::ActivationQueryBase class (here NewsAction) you  define the activate-method, for example like this:

```
sc::ActivationResponse NewsAction::activate()
{
    initScope();

    if (openWithoutPreview) {
        return sc::ActivationResponse(sc::ActivationResponse::Status::NotHandled);
    }

    return sc::ActivationResponse(sc::ActivationResponse::Status::ShowPreview);
}
```

(watch the activation responce: NotHandled tells the scope to send it to the external dispatcher.)

3: Finally, if create the cards (CategorisedResult) in the searchquery-class, you have to tell them to intercept the activation. (Result.set_intercept_activation()) For example, like this:

```
for (const Result &result : results) {
    sc::CategorisedResult card(category);

    fillCard(card, result);
    card.set_intercept_activation();

    // Push the result
    if (!reply->push(card)) {
        // If we fail to push, it means the query has been cancelled.
        // So don't continue;
        return;
    }
}
```

I found the solution (hidden) in this manual:
https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/scopes/cpp/development/index/